# Where can I find the ERD of OpenStreetMap database?

Tags: openstreetmap, erd

I need the Entity Relationship Diagram for OpenStreetMap. Or something that could make it very easy for me to get accustomed to the design of the OSM database.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really anything fancy like an ERD for the database. The primary definition of the schema is the rails migrations, which you can find here:

https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/tree/master/db/migrate

There is also a (hopefully up to date) dump of the resulting schema in SQL form here:

https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/db/structure.sql

Unless you're actually developing code for the OpenStreetMap web site however you probably don't need to know any of this - if you just want to work with OpenStreetMap data you will probably be better off loading the data into a database with a schema targeted at your intended use case rather than one targeted at supporting editing of the data.